# Node JS browser simulation (cookies, sessions, headers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, browser, request

I need to make requests from node js like a normal browser. 
What do I mean ?

1. I can set any HTTP information, like cookies, headers, body. So to built HTTP request as I want.
2. After the request is made, all response data should be readable, like `Set Cookie`....
3. It would be great if cookies could be saved automatically for the time of a session. So I don't need to include them each time all further request are made.
4. So just simulate a real browser in order to keep session

Is there any library of framework that could provide such functionality ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For situations where you don't need to parse HTML or run client-side JavaScript, you can use simple tools like Request or SuperAgent:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent

For more complicated scenarios you can use tools like JSDom:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

For even more complicated situations you can use tools like PhantomJS:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phantom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs

Something like PhantomJS, Headless Chrome or some other headless browser instead of just a DOM implementation will be most flexible because it is a real browser, just without a visible window. JSDom and similar tools are DOM implementations and some of them can execute client-side JavaScript but those are not real browsers. And things like Request and SuperAgent are simple HTTP clients that don't parse HTML or execute client-side scripts by themselves but they still let you handle cookies and headers.

More options:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/zombie
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/headless
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/zombie-phantom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/headless-browser-lite
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-headless-chromium

Comment: Great answer !! Appreciate your help

Comment: Also see [nightmarejs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) if you want to fully simulate a browser (it uses electron under the hood)

Comment: phantomjs is deprecated, prefer WhiteAngel answer

Answer (score 5):

With the latest versions of Chrome/Chromium you can use them directly in **headless** mode.
Here's the package that adds Chromium to your NodeJS project and allows to perform automation in headless mode: https://github.com/dtolstyi/node-chromium

Comment: Where can I find the documentation of this?

Comment: Hi @Leo. All needed docs to install and use package are on github page. All additional options and usages are not related to package but to webdriver or any other method of controlling the browser you chose.