Powershell - Parsing HTML Table Using Invoke-WebRequest
I have the following Powershell script to fetch a table from a webpage:
$url = 'https://www.cropex.hr/en/market-data/day-ahead-market/day-ahead-market-results.html'
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$table = @($page.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table'))[0]
$outputFile = 'D:\cropex\trading\table.html'
$table.OuterHTML | Set-Content -Path $outputFile

It worked like a charm until recently. But nowadays I only get empty table.html (i.e. no data). No error message.
In my understanding, the issue is with parsing the html element with the tag 'table'. But when I inspect the webpage, I clearly see a tag 'table'.
I would appreciate if anybody would give me a hand with that.

have you moved from Powershell Desktop(5.1) to Powershell Core(7+) by chance?

Daniel, I tried it out. I changed the original code the following way:
'$parsedHtml.QuerySelectorAll('table').InnerHtml | Set-Content -Path $outputFile'
I'm only getting the very first column of the table I'm interested in. How do I get the  rest?

Currently the Table is generated dynamically by Javascript.
You can check it by opening the page with javascript disabled, or have Invoke-WebRequest download the page as-it and check the code locally.
Evidently it has been a new development.
Invoke-WebRequest doesn't elaborate any script, so you get the page without it.

I downloaded the page by using Invoke-WebRequest but I still don't get the table of interest in it.

That's the point: the table is dynamically generated by the browser using Javascript.
Invoke-WebRequest does NOT do that. So you have no <table>.

sirtao,  I misunderstood your suggestion. How, then, do I save that webpage locally, but with the table in it?

that's a different question. Luckily it has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821256/how-do-you-load-a-web-page-in-powershell-that-requires-javascript

sirtao, After a few hours of trying to make PSParseHTML give what I need, I admit that I don't know how to get that JS table :(
